# Multiple XHR requests are slow

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, yii

I've created an Angular.js application that issues multiple XHR requests to a PHP application built with Yii framework. Problem is that it seems like that the multiple requests slow down each other - but I don't know why. Please see this image from Google Chrome developer tools:

[image]

It is okay that the last three requests wait for a few milli seconds. This is because Chrome allows only six concurrent requests. My problem is e.g. that request 8, 9 and 10 takes 6-8 seconds. When I copy the URL of these requests and open them one by one in my browser, they only take < 800ms. How could this possibly be? Is this a problem located in Apache or a client issue? How can I track this down easily?

Comment: This sounds like you have a bottleneck in your PHP/Yii code that makes it so that multiple requests cannot run concurrently.  This is often caused by contention for some shared resource such as a database.  We would have to see your server-side code and know more about it to offer any more specific ideas beyond a broad guess like this.

Comment: Do you use `$_SESSION` in the PHP script you call? The session file is locked per request. Calling `session_write_close()` as soon as you're done with it should help.